# pass logging config file in python as a command line argument

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-logging

I have a logging config file named logging.conf as below:

```
    [loggers]
    keys=root,simpleExample

    [handlers]
    keys=consoleHandler

    [formatters]
    keys=simpleFormatter

    [logger_root]
    level=DEBUG
    handlers=consoleHandler

    [logger_simpleExample]
    level=DEBUG
    handlers=consoleHandler
    qualname=simpleExample
    propagate=0

    [handler_consoleHandler]
    class=StreamHandler
    level=DEBUG
    formatter=simpleFormatter
    args=(sys.stdout,)

    [formatter_simpleFormatter]
    format=%(asctime)s - %(name)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s
```

I can add it to my python code using `logging.config.fileConfig('logging.conf')` and it works.

Is there a way to pass this file as a runtime argument when I run my python script from command line ?

I cannot use options like argparser to parse the arguments and then setting the file using `logging.config.fileConfig()`. My python code runs as a docker image and I cannot modify the docker image. Is there an argument provided by logging module that I can use?

Comment: You're asking how to pass the filename as an argument on the command line, but also saying you cannot parse the command line because you cannot modify the docker image. So are you saying you cannot pass arguments and are looking for an alternative way to pass the file? You could list any .conf file present and load that? Or include the text of the .conf verbatim in your script and load through StringIO?

Comment: I can patch the docker image to include the config file in it, but is there a command line argument that I can set which makes logger honor it?

Comment: Ah I see, you want to know if your script will take command line parameters that `logging.config` will pick up, even though you cannot change the script to parse the parameters yourself? I don't think that's the case - it's not technically impossible for a module to do so, but I don't think `logging.config` or `fileConfig()` does.